# how to extract the following keywords containing cells from all columns of csv dataset and copy to new Analysis column

Tags: python, nlp, dataset, pandas, data-cleaning

1. ```
     useData_list = ['Appeal Allowed','Appeal failed and
    dismissed','Appeal dismissed','petition allowed','order
     accordingly','petition dismissed','appeal dismissed without any
     order as to cost','Appeal disposed of','Appeal partly
      allowed','Petition disposed of','No costs'] 

     regstr ='|'.join(user_list)



   datacontain=df[df.apply(lambdacolumn:column.astype(str).str.contains(regst).any(),axis=1)]
       df["Analysis"]=datacontain.copy()
          df.to_csv('updated90.csv',index=False)
          df.to_csv('updated90.csv',index=False)

           KeyError Traceback (most    recent call last)
   ```

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self,
key, method, tolerance)
2894             try:
-> 2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
2896             except KeyError as err:

pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.h
...
:
:
129         if self._validate_ndim and self.ndim and len(self.mgr_locs) != len(self.values):
--> 130             raise ValueError(
131                 f"Wrong number of items passed {len(self.values)}, "
132                 f"placement implies {len(self.mgr_locs)}"

```
                 ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 325, placement                       implies 1
```

Comment: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 325, placement implies 1

Comment: Can you present us some example input data and expected output?